# Getting DataFlowClientException in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

When I am trying to give the below command in shell I am getting the below error.
Can you please let me know why I am getting this error. I am trying to execute the below link program

Maven Repository local: C:\maven

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/cloud-data-flow

```
Error :

    dataflow:>app register --name source-app --type source --uri maven://com.spring.cloud:soruce:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    dataflow:>app register --name processor-app --type processor --uri maven://com.spring.cloud:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    dataflow:>app register --name sink-app --type sink --uri maven://com.spring.cloud:sink:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    stream create --name log-data --definition 'source-app | processor-app | sink-app'

 dataflow:>stream deploy --name log-data
        Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Failed to resolve MavenResource: com.javainuse:sink:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Configured remote repository: : [springRepo]
```

springcloud data flow local Server:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve MavenResource: com.javainuse:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Configured remote repository: : [springRepo]
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.javainuse:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.spring.clouddata</groupId>
  <artifactId>sourceapp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>sourceapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Brixton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>      

    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the apps you register via `app register` are indeed in the corresponding maven repository. It looks like you don't have them pushed. In case if you have your apps in custom maven repositories, then [configure](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-maven) the maven repository.

Also, the app that SCDF server complains is different from what you registered above.

Comment: I am connecting to my local repository only.Please let me know how to connect to my local maven repository.

Comment: The property `--maven.localRepository` points to your local maven repository. By default, it points to <UserHome>/.m2/repository.

Comment: Hi Gopinath, Can you please explain me what is the "the app that SCDF server complains is different from what you registered above." spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.3.0.M1
spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.3.0.M1
spring cloud version:Brixton.SR7
Spring boot version:1.5.9.RELEASE

Comment: You get the exception: Could not find artifact `com.javainuse:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` while you only registered the app `maven://com.spring.cloud:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`